# How to cast an Collection<x> to an IQueryable<x>

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am trying to set up a moq, but i am needing to create a fake IQueryable. i made a Collection but i am at a loss of how to cast that to an IQueryable.

```
Collection<DetailDataEntity> DetailDataEntityCollection = 
    new Collection<DetailDataEntity>();

DetailDataEntity DetailDataEntity = new DetailDataEntity();
DetailDataEntity.FeedTypeID = 1;
DetailDataEntityCollection.Add(DetailDataEntity);


_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDetail(It.IsAny<Int32>(),
                                       It.IsAny<Enum.FeedTypeEnum.FeedType>())) 
               .Returns(DetailDataEntityCollection);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call `AsQueryable` on your collection.

```
_mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDetail(It.IsAny<Int32>(), 
                                       It.IsAny<Enum.FeedTypeEnum.FeedType>()))
               .Returns(DetailDataEntityCollection.AsQueryable());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a simple ICollection object and found that this worked for me:

```
var tapSettings = xfmrTapSettings.ToList().AsQueryable();
```

I had to use ToList in front of AsQueryable to make it work.